# grid view won't update database (no errors)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a page with a details view and a grid view (each with their own data source. I can't figure out why the update says it's successful but don't update the table. the details view works fine. The grid view is only suppose to show data related to what's in the details view. If I hard code the values in the source it works but when I change it back it blows up. here's my code

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource OnUpdated="dsCar_Updated" ID="dsCar" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT Car.* FROM Car WHERE (VIN = ?)" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE Car SET [Branch ID] = ?, [State Registration] = ?, [License Plate] = ?, Color = ?, Model = ?, [Car Year] = ?, [Plate Expiration] = ? WHERE (VIN = ?)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="?" QueryStringField="VIN" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            DataSourceID="dsCar" Height="50px" Width="265px" CellPadding="4" 
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="VIN" DefaultMode="Edit">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VIN" HeaderText="VIN" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="VIN" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Branch Name" SortExpression="Branch ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList %>" 
                            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList.ProviderName %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Branch]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Branch Name" 
                            DataValueField="Branch ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("[Branch ID]") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList %>" 
                            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList.ProviderName %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Branch]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Branch Name" 
                            DataValueField="Branch ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("[Branch ID]") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList %>" 
                            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList.ProviderName %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Branch]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Branch Name" 
                            DataValueField="Branch ID" Enabled="False" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("[Branch ID]") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="State Registration" HeaderText="State Registration" 
                    SortExpression="State Registration" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="License Plate" HeaderText="License Plate" 
                    SortExpression="License Plate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Color" HeaderText="Color" SortExpression="Color" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Model" SortExpression="Model">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList %>" 
                            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList.ProviderName %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Model]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="Model Name" 
                            DataValueField="ModelID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Model") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Model") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList %>" 
                            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList.ProviderName %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Model]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="Model Name" 
                            DataValueField="ModelID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Model") %>' 
                            Enabled="False">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Car Year" HeaderText="Car Year" 
                    SortExpression="Car Year" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Plate Expiration" 
                    SortExpression="Plate Expiration">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList %>" 
                            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList.ProviderName %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Car]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
                            onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" 
                            VisibleDate='<%# Eval("[Plate Expiration]") %>' 
                            SelectedDate='<%# Bind("[Plate Expiration]") %>'></asp:Calendar>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateEdit" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("[Plate Expiration]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
                            onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" 
                            VisibleDate='<%# Eval("[Plate Expiration]") %>'></asp:Calendar>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("[Plate Expiration]") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[Plate Expiration]") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>

<asp:SqlDataSource OnUpdated="dsMaintance_Updated" ID="dsMaintance" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Maintenance] WHERE [MainteanceID] = ?" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Maintenance] ([MainteanceID], [VIN], [Procedure ID], [Date]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT MainteanceID, VIN, [Procedure ID], [Date] FROM Maintenance WHERE (VIN = ?)" 


            UpdateCommand="UPDATE Maintenance SET [Procedure ID] = ?, [Date] = ? WHERE (MainteanceID = ?)">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="MainteanceID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="MainteanceID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="VIN" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Procedure_ID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="VIN" QueryStringField="VIN" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="MainteanceID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="VIN" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Procedure_ID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" />

            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="MainteanceID" DataSourceID="dsMaintance" BackColor="White" 
            BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" 
            CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MainteanceID" HeaderText="MainteanceID" 
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MainteanceID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VIN" HeaderText="VIN" SortExpression="VIN" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Procedure ID" HeaderText="Procedure ID" 
                    SortExpression="Procedure ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the proper parameters to the `UpdateParameters` section. It looks like you have a *copy-paste* problem (maybe you copied the section from the `InsertParameters` section). Your `UPDATE` statement needs only 3 parameters.

Comment: is there a command to let me see in a textbox the sql line that is executing with the values it should be using?

Comment: could you post the current version of your code, after updating the `UpdateParameters` section?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource OnUpdated="dsMaintance_Updated" ID="dsMaintance" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Maintenance] WHERE [MainteanceID] = ?" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Maintenance] ([MainteanceID], [VIN], [Procedure ID], [Date]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehicalList.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT MainteanceID, VIN, [Procedure ID], [Date] FROM Maintenance WHERE (VIN = ?)"  
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE Maintenance SET [Procedure ID] = ?, [Date] = ? WHERE (MainteanceID = ?)">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="MainteanceID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="MainteanceID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="VIN" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Procedure_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="VIN" QueryStringField="VIN" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <%--<asp:Parameter Name="MainteanceID" Type="Int32" />--%>
            <%--<asp:Parameter Name="VIN" Type="String" />--%>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Procedure_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" />   
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: A little explanation with your code can help the OP understand what the issue is... That said, Welcome to SO

Comment: my instructor helped fix it ... 2 things here 1 I forgot the brackets around Mainteance in the update command and he told me to just completely delete the updateparameters and somehow it works ... not sure I understand why but it works now ... :\